# how to remove \0 (whitespace character) from the middle of pointer string in c

Tags: c, string, pointers

hello im new to programming and i have a question. I made the program below for my programming classes and i have a problem when i submit the answer. The results are visibly correct but when i check the whitespace characters output this happens: **(what i need is conclusion is a way to remove '\0' from the middle of the pointer string)**

**input :**

3

7 Hello World

20
Hello World

30 The story, told by the sixyear-old Jean Louise Finch,
takes place during three years
(1933–35) of the Great
Depression in the fictional
town of Maycomb, Alabama, the
seat of Maycomb County.

**the expected output (with whitespace characters) :**

Hello W\n

Hello World*********\n

The story, told by t**********\n

\n

**my output ( whitespace characters) :**

Hello W\n

Hello World\0*********\n

The story, told by t\0**********\n

\n

**and my source code is :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char *s;
  int n,i,k,l,j,o,p;
  s = malloc(51*(sizeof(char)));
  scanf("%d",&n);
  for (i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d ",&k);
    fgets(s,21,stdin);
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
    l = strlen(s);
    if (l==k)
    {
      printf("%s\n",s);
    }
    else if (l>k)
    {
      for (j=0;j<k;j++)
      {
        printf("%c",s[j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    else if (l<k)
    {
      s = realloc(s,(k+1)*sizeof(char));
      for (o=l+1;o<=k;o++)
      {
        s[o]='*';
      }
      s[k+1]='\0'
      for (p=0;p<=k;p++)
      {
        printf("%c",s[p]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you literally have `\0` in your string then you have more than one string. (Or you have a string and other memory...) The `\0` is the string terminator in C. If you are reading past one -- you are a test pilot.

Comment: Sounds like what you *really* need is a way to not have the `\0` in there in the first place.

Comment: sorry my bad...

Comment: there is a scanf for k every loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537/what-can-i-use-for-input-conversion-instead-of-scanf

Comment: i am already using fgets for the string i believe. And the problem is with the string not the integers

Comment: Why are you inserting the null character into your string in the first place?

Comment: First of all, `\0` is not "whitespace".  Whitespace is a catch-all term for characters that don't put any "ink" on the "paper".  The normal whitespace characters are space `' '`, tab `'\t'`, and newline `'\n'`.  The null character `\0` is completely different: it's an invisible marker which marks the *end* of a string, and therefore never appears *in* a string.

Comment: Your problem, I think, is that you've got one place where you forgot that strings and arrays in C are 0-based.  If string `s` has length `l`, the valid characters in the string run from `0` to `l-1`, and the next character "after" the string is `l`.  So in the `l<k` case, where you're appending `*` characters at the end of the string with the loop `for(o=l+1; o<=k; o++)`, that should really be `for(o=l; o<k; o++)`.

Comment: Another minor problem is that you're allocating 51 characters for `s`, but then telling `fgets` that the size is 21.  But you're certainly not going to be able to read the string "The story, told by the sixyear-old Jean Louise Finch, takes place during three years (1933–35) of the Great Depression in the fictional town of Maycomb, Alabama, the seat of Maycomb County.".

Comment: You have `scanf("%d ",&k);` — [What is the effect of trailing white space in a `scanf()` format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19499060/15168) explains why that is a bad idea.